# ComboBox Hightlight item and also highlight browsed items

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, blend

I am a graphic designer who is new to WPF and XAML. I want to create a ComboBox in which the selected item stays selected until a new item is choosen. At the same time, when the user wants to mouse over other items, I want to show a different color for the highlight. I am using blend and c#.

If that's a bit confusing I did a quick illustration. Thanks!!

This is a link to my image:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/jeddahbalgame/6633558209/

Comment: WTH, i am not going to join G+ just to look at that image, please upload it elsewhere, and use the provided upload mechanism if possible...

Comment: Sorry about that. Ever since google + , I can't have people look at my pictures unless they join. Here's another link to my flickr with the image:http://www.flickr.com/photos/jeddahbalgame/6633558209/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Trigger to specify what color the item should be when it is selected

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

To change the color of the item the mouse is over, you actually have to overwrite the HighlightBrush for the ComboBox since it is a system color. You can also do this in your Style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow"/>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you could do this, either using Code-Behind on the `SelectionChanged` event or by using Binding and `OnPropertyChanged` event from that item or have your Details view be bound to the SelectedItem of the combo box.

Binding is the preferred method and is very useful but will take some time to learn. I'd recommend searching around for WPF Binding Tutorials, using MVVM pattern.

MVVM: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/03/binding-combo-boxes-in-wpf-with-mvvm.html

If you just mean having a different background / highlight color on the combobox itself and nothing else on the page changing, then you'll want to Stylize your ComboBox.

You might need to use DataTriggers depending on exactly what you want, I can't tell since I can't view your image.

Stylizing: http://www.uxpassion.com/2008/09/styling-wpf-listbox-highlight-color/ (yes its ugly but the basics are there)

DataTriggers: [How do you highlight an item in a combobox using WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833103/how-do-you-highlight-an-item-in-a-combobox-using-wpf)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll check it out!